# installshield автообновления

Tags: installshield

Добрый день!

Не подскажете, как можно настроить автобновление при создание инсталлятора в `InstallShield`?

Comment: спасибо, попробую))

Comment: Немного не понял вопроса.
Обновление чего: приложения, собранного через InstallShield или самого InstallShield-а?

Comment: приложения, собранного через installshield. Само приложение представляет собой набор dll и является немного переработанным vlc плагином для использования его через браузеры. Просто vlc время от времени обновляется и улучшается и хотелось бы некоторые dll из моего приложения автоматически обновлять, что бы не делать каждый раз инсталлятор, только как это настроить никак не пойму(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если знаете английский, имеет смысл посмотреть вот это:
[Patching and Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(VS.85).aspx)

Но вообще-то тема довольно мутная. Особо помочь я тут не смогу.

Само создание патчей спрятано в installation designer->media->patch design.
В additional External files вроде можно выбрать, какие файлы обновлять.

[Аналогичный вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792412/create-upgrade-patch-for-installshield-installer)